# React & d3 combination prevents mousedown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm using react together with d3 (the new v4), but it seems that the d3 zoom behaviour is conflicting with the way react events are handled.

I'm trying to attach a mousedown event listener, to the `<rect>` svg element. For some reason, when attaching the listener via react, the d3 listener is triggered before the listener attached via react. Because d3 stops any further propagation, my listener is never called.

But when i attach the listener directly via pure javascript or disable the zoom behaviour, it works.

[See this example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzLOaB?editors=1011)

```
class Rectangle extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // get main d3 selector
    this.canvas = d3.select('#react-root svg');
    // init the pan & zoom behaviour
    this.zoom = d3.zoom()
      .on('start', () => {
        console.log('zoom started!');
      })
      .on('zoom', () => {
        console.log('zooming!');
      });
    this.canvas.call(this.zoom);

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      console.log("window mousedown!");
    });

    document.querySelector('#react-root svg rect').addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      console.log('rect mousedown! (via pure js)');
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg onMouseDown={() => console.log('svg mousedown! (via react)')}>
        <rect
          rx="10" ry="10"
          width="100" height="100"
          onMouseDown={() => console.log('rect mousedown! (via react)')}
          onTouchStart={() => console.log('touch down!')}
        />
      </svg>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<Rectangle />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that D3 is removing your React Events from the `<rect>` after the component mounts.

That's not a problem because D3 allows you to register multiple listeners for the same event using `type.name`.

eg : `start.native` & `start.react`.

How can you apply this to your code? Like this

```
class Rectangle extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvas = d3.select('#react-root svg');
    this.zoom = d3.zoom()
      .on('start.native', () => {
        console.log('mouse down using pure js');
      })
      .on('end.native', () => {
        console.log('mouse up using pure js');
      })
      .on('start.react',this.onMouseDownWithReact)
      .on('end.react', this.onMouseUpWithReact);
    this.canvas.call(this.zoom);
  }
  onMouseDownWithReact(){
    console.log("Mouse Down with react");
  }
  onMouseUpWithReact(){
    console.log("Mouse Up with react");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <svg onMouseDown={() => console.log('svg mousedown! (via react)')}>
        <rect
          rx="10" ry="10"
          width="100" height="100"
        />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i would actually like to keep using the react way of binding event listeners, if possible.